# Firebase receives update but doesn't trigger .on('child_changed')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When I first load the page, firebase works just fine. Any change to any of the data points triggers this function:

```
database.ref('users').on('child_changed, function...)
```

However, when I log out, and then log back in I can see the database being updated but the change is not triggering anymore until I reload the page. After reload, any change is reflected properly, but somehow logout/login stops the listening for change.

I wouldn't want users to have to reload every time they want to log out and then log back in.

Do I need another Firebase listener perhaps? I didn't find any other than these four:

```
child_removed, child_changed, child_added, value,
```

so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can find more listeners here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes thank you! I looked at them but nothing works. I tried multiple ways to listen for change but it doesn't work unless I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! Instead of having the database listeners inside angular .run() method, I refactored the code so listeners are inside of .factory(). Now every time user logs in/out the factory is consulted for any changes in the database.

That enables automatic update of the DOM elements every time something changes on the client and in the database.